# RedBeanPHP не создает таблицу

Tags: php, sql, redbeanphp

Только начал разбираться с RedBeanPHP, и на текущий момент не могу создать вторую таблицу посредством запроса R::dispense

```
    <?php 
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/inc/db.php";
$data = $_POST;
$task_des = $data['task_des'];
$link_adress = $data['link_adress'];
$account = $data['account'];
$account_val = $data['account_val'];
var_dump($_POST);
    if( isset($data['task_new']))
    {
        $errors = array();
        if( R::count('task_accs', "link_adress = ?", array($link_adress)) > 0){
            $errors[] = 'Такая запись уже есть';
        }
        echo "<br>ok";
        if(empty($errors)){
            $task = R::dispense('task_accs');
            $task->task_des = $task_des;
            $task->link_adress = $link_adress;
            $task->account_val = $account_val;
            echo "ok2";
            R::store($task);
            echo "ok3";

        } else {
            echo '<div style="color: red;">'.array_shift($errors).'</div><br>';
        }
    }
    echo "ok4";
?>
```

Итогом я получаю следующее: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код подобного рода отрабатывает корректно, создает таблицу и заносит параметры:

```
<?php 
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/inc/db.php");

$data = $_POST;

    if( isset($data['sign']))
    {
        $user = R::dispense('users');
        $user->login = $data['login'];
        $user->password = password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        R::store($user);
    }
?>
```

Скорее всего, я не замечаю какую-то мелочь, заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: судя по коду вы строки в таблице создаете, а не саму таблицу

Comment: включите вывод сообщений об ошибках, и гляньте что напишет.

Comment: сама таблица то вообще создана у вас?

Comment: Спасибо, нашел причину раскопав документацию. 
Согласно ей, нельзя в имени указывать спец.символы и заглавные буквы.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел причину, согласно документации нельзя в имени таблицы указывать спец.символы и заглавные буквы.

Comment: добавьте, что это конкретно было для данного примера кода. заглавных букв вроде не видно. а подчеркивание спец.символом что ли считается?

Comment: R::dispense('task_accs');
Заменил на:
R::dispense('taskaccs');
Все прошло.